# magento: M1 1.9.3.1 to M2 data upgrade script sql error: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: upgrade, magento2

I'm upgrading Magento 1.9.3.1 store to Magento 2.1.5 and currently running **data migration**. Which shows below error.

**Error :**
    [PDOException]
      SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

**Command : php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce\1.9.3.1\config.xml**

**Process :**

```
Reset the current position of migration to start from the beginning

[2017-07-19 10:41:16][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-07-19 10:41:18][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens



migrate:data [-r|--reset] config
```

Comment: can you check without --rest

Comment: I tried without reset but it display same error again